# Select sibling elements on hover

Tags: css, hover

**Goals:**

- When hovering on `.one` I want both `.two` and `.three` to use the
  same BG image.
- When hovering on `.two` I want both `.one` and `.three` to use the
  same BG image.
- When hovering on `.three` I want both `.one` and `.two` to use the
  same BG image.

It seems like the sibling selector doesn't allow previous sibling elements on `:hover`. Is there a solution for this?

```css
.item{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.one,
.one:hover ~ .two,
.one:hover ~ .three{
  background: url('https://placeimg.com/200/200/nature');
}

.two,
.two:hover ~ .one,
.two:hover ~ .three{
  background: url('https://placeimg.com/200/200/arch');
}

.three,
.three:hover ~ .one,
.three:hover ~ .two{
  background: url('https://placeimg.com/200/200/tech');
}
```

```html
<div class="item one"></div>
<div class="item two"></div>
<div class="item three"></div>
```

---

**UPDATE:** Looks like there is no CSS solution for this but I did create a jQuery solution.

```js
$('.one').hover(
 function(){ $('.two, .three').addClass('one-all') },
  function(){ $('.two, .three').removeClass('one-all') }  
);

$('.two').hover(
 function(){ $('.one, .three').addClass('two-all') }, 
  function(){ $('.one, .three').removeClass('two-all') }    
);

$('.three').hover(
 function(){ $('.one, .two').addClass('three-all') },   
  function(){ $('.one, .two').removeClass('three-all') }    
);
```

```css
.item{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

/* original images */
.one{ background: url('https://placeimg.com/200/200/nature');}
.two{ background: url('https://placeimg.com/200/200/arch');}
.three{ background: url('https://placeimg.com/200/200/tech');}

/* replacement images*/
.one-all{ background: url('https://placeimg.com/200/200/nature');}
.two-all{ background: url('https://placeimg.com/200/200/arch');}
.three-all{ background: url('https://placeimg.com/200/200/tech');}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item one"></div>
<div class="item two"></div>
<div class="item three"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a "previous sibling" CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there is no "previous sibling" selector in CSS (see the [complete list](https://kolosek.com/css-selectors/)).

Note that it is possible to play with the *Flexbox* `order` property to simulate previous sibling selection but next sibling selection can't be applied thereafter.

You'll need to go JavaScript on this one.

Comment: Looks like i will have to use a JS solution, thanks!